# Why doesn't the member of the base class keep the value it was first initialized with in the constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class B {

protected:
    int x;
public:
    B() {
        x = 78;
    }

};
class D1 : virtual public B {
public:
    D1() {
        x = 15;
    }

};
class D2 : virtual public B {
public:
    D2() {
        x = 37;
    }


};
class C : public D2, public D1 {
public:
    int get_x() {
        return x;
    }

};
int main()
{
    C ob;
    cout << ob.get_x();
    return 0;
}
```

when the C object is created, the value of x is 15 instead of 78. I was wondering if it's because the last constructor called(which changed the value of x) was the D1 constructor?

Comment: I suggest adding `cout` statements in your constructors in order to see what order they are executed.

Comment: You aren't doing initialization with `x`. It's being assigned to in the body of each c'tor. Initialization would be `B() : x(78) {}`

Comment: It is not clear why expect it to keep original value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if it's because the last constructor called(which changed the value of x) was the D1 constructor?

Yes, that is exactly what happened. A class's base constructors are called in the order the ancestors are listed. Since `D1` is listed last, its constructor is called last. `B'`s constructor is called first to initialize `x` to 78, then `D2`'s constructor overwrites `x` with 37, then `D1`'s constructor overwrites `x` with 15.